# How to run docker-compose up --build silently

Tags: linux, windows, bash, docker, shell

The command `docker-compose up --build` will output build process and options like `--quiet`, `--quiet-pull` or `--log-level ERROR` won't work.

I also didn't find any other options in the documents.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on linux:

```bash
docker-compose up --build 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

If you are on Windows:

```bash
docker-compose up --build > nul 2> nul
```

Comment: bash `... &> /dev/null`